# how to get the element of a list inside jsp using JSTL?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have such this code inside my Spring MVC java controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "jobs", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
public String jobList(@PathVariable("username") String username, Model model) {
    JobInfo[] jobInfo;
    JobStatistics js;
    LinkedList<JobStatistics> jobStats = new LinkedList<JobStatistics>();
    try {
        jobInfo = uiClient.getJobs(username);
           for (int i = 0; i < jobInfo.length; i++) {
             js = uiClient.getJobStatistics(jobInfo[i].getJobId());
             jobStats.add(js);
           }
        model.addAttribute("jobs", jobInfo);
        model.addAttribute("jobStats", jobStats);
    }
```

which uiClient will get some data from database using RMI ...
now I want to show the jobs & related statistic inside my JSP file using JSTL :

```
<c:set var="stats" value="${jobStats}" />
        <c:forEach var="jobs" items="${jobs}">
           <c:set var="jobID" value="${jobs.JobId}"/>
          <table>
            <tr class="tr1">
                <td>${jobs.Topic}</td>
                <td>${stats.get(i).No}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </c:forEach>
```

How do I get the `LinkedList` elements of Model inside my JSP using JSTL? There might be no no counter `i` been put in scope for me.

Comment: I would also use var="job"  instead of var="jobs" in case you want to reference the original "jobs"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In my opinion, the right answer is a combination of both of the answers you got:

> use varStatus attribute of c:foreach tag

but:

> "get" is not a jstl function.

```
<c:forEach var="jobs" items="${jobs}" varStatus="i">
   <c:set var="jobID" value="${jobs.jobId}"/>
  <table>
    <tr class="tr1">
        <td>${jobs.topic}</td>
        <td>${stats[i.index].no}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</c:forEach>
```

EDIT: this is the code finally used by the author of the question:

```
<c:set var="stats" value="${jobStats}" />
<c:forEach items="${jobs}" varStatus="i">
   <c:set var="jobID" value="${jobs[i.index].jobId}"/>
  <table>
    <tr class="tr1">
        <td>${jobs[i.index].topic}</td>
        <td>${stats[i.index].no}</td>
        <td>${jobID}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I tried ur solution but there is a problem: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type rs.ui.JobInfo

Comment: mm that's weird. Is your 'stats' variable the `LinkedList` instance?

Comment: yeah, I defined it like what I did above ...
but my JobInfo is an array

Comment: Oh, I think I found the mistake. The attribute access' first letter should be lowercase. I'll edit the answer. Assuming those objects have 'getJobId', 'getTopic' and 'getNo' getters.

Comment: I edited your code & made that the final answer (for those who want to know about it *foreach item in java is like using 'var' in jstl & for iterating over a temporary variable use 'varStatus' instead in JSTL but never use both of them at the same time inside <c:forEach)... thnx for all contributions Fellas ...

Comment: please confirm the edited document & I then I will rate it as an accepted answer .

Comment: @Mehdi It's been rejected by the community so I couldn't find a way to accept it :/ Also, I think you can actually use both 'var' and 'varStatus' at the same time without any problem. Anyway, if using it like you say worked for you...

Comment: @Mehdi I added your code to the answer though you won't get any reputation this way :/ sorry

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if we can use both var & varStatus at the same time but my problem got solved when I did that, there's no problem for the reputation man, at least we share something that other people can use also :) thanx so much

Answer (score 7):

`get` is not a jstl function.

```
<td>${stats[i.index].No}</td>
```

Comment: OP's code would have worked when using EL 2.2. The only problem left is providing the proper value of `i`, which is nowhere visible in the code provided so far (and also explicitly been mentioned by the OP as the concrete problem).

Comment: I tried ur solution but there is a problem:
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type rs.ui.JobInfo

Comment: It's the most useful answer

Answer (score 3):

use `varStatus` attribute of `c:foreach`  tag

```
<c:forEach var="jobs" items="${jobs}" varStatus="i">
   <c:set var="jobID" value="${jobs.JobId}"/>
  <table>
    <tr class="tr1">
        <td>${jobs.Topic}</td>
        <td>${stats.get(i.index).No}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</c:forEach>
```