# java collection usage as map and retrieving data

Tags: java, jsp, dictionary, arraylist, jstl

```
Map<String, List<OfferBean>> map = new HashMap<String, List<OfferBean>>();
            List<OfferBean> al=new ArrayList<OfferBean>();
            OfferBean of=null;
            sql="select * from catgory";
            ps1=c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps1.execute();
            rs=ps1.getResultSet();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println("inside loop of if");
                sql="select * from catgory";
                ps1=c.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps1.execute();
                rs=ps1.getResultSet();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    of=new OfferBean();
                    System.out.println("inside loop of while");
                    of.setCategory(rs.getString("catgoryname"));
                    al.add(of);
                }
           map.put("key", al);
```

i want use two `ArrayList` the both `ArrayList` i will put inside `HashMap` by using key and i want to pass to the `jsp` side in the `jsp` side i want retrieve the data using `jstl` how to reteive it plz any one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.setAttribute("myMap", map);   

<c:forEach items="${myMap}" var="mapEntry">
     key : ${mapEntry.key} 
     <c:forEach items="${mapEntry.value}" var="item">
        Category :  ${item.category}
     </c:forEach><br>
 <c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 request.setAttribute("sampleMap", map);
```

Try [c:forEach](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm)

```
 <c:forEach var="sample" items="${sampleMap}">
     Key : ${sample.key}
   <c:forEach var="list" items="${sample.value}">
          Category - ${list.category} //you can access all the values of `OfferBean`
    </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
```

Take a look for accessing the [element of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353054/how-to-get-the-element-of-a-list-inside-jsp-using-jstl)

Comment: sorry can u plz help wht is that    Value - ${list.name} thnks

Comment: ${list.name} this for sample you can place the variables of the OfferBean

Comment: @user2734962 replace  ${list.name} with ${item.category}

Comment: ya correct. I dont know what are the variables inside the OfferBean so only i used the name for sample

Comment: how can i able to place those values inside textboxes

Comment: Place the input text attribute value="${item.category}"

Comment: Value - ${list.name} can i replace with input text attribute value="${item.category}"

Comment: <option>----</option>
  <c:if test="${requestScope.list!=null}">
 <c:forEach var="sample" items="${sampleMap}">
  Key : ${sample.key}
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${sample.value}">
 <option>"${item.category}"</option>  
  </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach> it is not working can u plz tell me is this correct

Comment: i'm not getting the values inside option

Comment: can you getting the key value

Comment: the problem is in the reference variable ${requestScope.list!=null} why are you checking the above condition. Where are you using the requestScope.list in java